# Send firebase database details in server

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a serious question. I make an android app where i send details in firebase relatime database. But how i send my firebase database details in my own server and store that in my mysql database.

Comment: Do you need to have two databases? Why are you using Firebase and not MySQL now? And why do you need to sync the data to your MySQL machine; can't you just query Firebase?

Comment: because i need a database in android. I use all orm's and databases. All database make app slow. Firebase only one they could't make app slow.

Comment: Okay, but you can use Firebase from your back-end code too, as Frank suggests below. I still don't see a need for a second database.

Answer (score 3):

To access the Firebase Database from your server, you use its Admin SDK. See the documentation for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start. There is no official PHP SDK for accessing the Firebase, but this open source package looks promising: https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

If you don't have control over the language on your server, consider using Cloud Functions which gives you a way to [run JavaScript/Node code in response to database updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), and then post to a (secured) PHP page that writes to your MySQL database.